# Any tutorials on accessing Azure SQL from a SharePoint hosted Silverlight webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online, silverlight, azure

So since SharePoint Lists have limited columns available for use, I'm now trying to write the output from my SharePoint hosted Silverlight app into a Windows Azure hosted SQL database.

Are there any good tutorials on how to read and write to SQL in Azure from Silverlight/SharePoint?

I'm using Silverlight 5, VB.Net, and SharePoint 2010 Foundation and SharePoint Online.

Thanks,

JT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best tutorial I've found for this is [Silverlight Sample Application with SQL Azure](http://www.scriptstar.co.uk/silverlight-sample-application-with-sql-azure/).

It walks you through connecting to Azure and performing a simple SQL Query.